# Why this list cloning result strangely (python 3.3)

Tags: python, python-3.3

sorry to ask this 'stupid' question, but i'm buffled with this problem for the past hours. I've been coding python for quite a while, and never had this kind of problem, but my laptop got stolen, so I installed python 3.3 on another computer. And when today I tried to do something with list cloning, i keep getting problem, so finally i tried this:

```
a = [[0, 1, 2],[-1, 0, 1],[-2, -1, 0]]
m = a[:]
m[1][1] = 'x'
print(m,a)
```

and the result is:

```
[[0, 1, 2], [-1, 'x', 1], [-2, -1, 0]]  [[0, 1, 2], [-1, 'x', 1], [-2, -1, 0]]
```

how come??? m should be a copy of a. I tried to `id(a)` and `id(m)` and they both shows different result. But still it results like that. Probably something wrong with my compiler? Please advise.

P.S. I've read the posts mentioned before I post this question. I know how to copy/clone a list. And usually I don't have any problems with it, until today. And perhaps to clarify my question, it's not how to correct it (since I have already work around it to get the correct results), but why the code behave like that when theorytically m = a[:] would result a new list with same value as a, and not just referring the same list as a.

P.P.S. Sorry, I read the posts mentioned again once more, and I found the answer there: [:] doesn't work for nested list. I didn't fully get/understand the term 'nested list' at first time read (English is not my mother language). Case closed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is right.

If you check `id(m[1])` and `id(a[1])`, you may find they refer to the same object.

I think the reason is that the list `a` and `m` just store reference to other objects, something like pointers in `C++`.

I should say this is a notice-worthy case when we consider making a replicate of `list` using `slicing`. Pretty good example!